# custome pipe with http call in angular 6 not returning value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I have made a custom **pipe** in **angular 6** with takes id as parameter and return it name after calling server (http call)

My pipe code is following

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { AjaxService } from '@shared/services/ajax.service';
import { activities } from '@shared/constants/activity.constant';
@Pipe({
name: 'getName'
})
export class GetNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor( private serviceManager: AjaxService,){

}
transform(value: any): any {
 if(!value )
return value;
 // return 'a';  // this work perfectly

this.serviceManager.getByParams(activities.getEducatorAndSupervisorName, 
{id:value}).subscribe(
    response => {
      if(response.status==1){
      console.log(response.data)

       return response.data.name;  // i want to return this.

      }
      else
      {

      }
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error)

    }
   )
 }

}
```

and using it this way

```
 <td>{{it.createdByUser.id | getName }}</td>
```

Comment: DON'T DO THIS. this will send http requests each time the change detection cycle runs

Comment: yes when i write Pure : false then it gone to halt browser :(

Answer (score 0):

If the function you're using to get your value is asynchronous, you will need to use an `AsyncPipe`.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-impure-asyncpipe

Right now, you are returning `response.data.name` only for the function that subscribes to the response. That's not the same as returning it for the actual `transform()` function. On the code frame that Angular runs the pipe function, it can't get the result of the asynchronous request - that's going to take time to come back.

Comment: How I can make async ? @Katana

Comment: browser goes to halt down when I use pure:false